# How can a string be converted into binary with the spaces intact?

Tags: objective-c, binary, space, converters

For my app, I want to convert an NSString to a NSMutableString containing the binary equivalent. All spaces must be put in the appropriate spot.

I've found a snippet that converts the string to binary, but all spaces are excluded. It looked like this more or less:

```
NSMutableString *str2 = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@""];
for(NSInteger numberCopy = str; numberCopy > 0; numberCopy >>=1) {
    //Prepend "0" or "1", depending on the bit
    [str2 insertString:((numberCopy & 1) ? @"1" : @"0") atIndex:0];
    }
```

Str is input, str2 is output.

For the version that includes spaces, I have an array divide the input string by `componentsSeparatedByString: @" "`, and then the binary converter snippet (above) to each array object. I add the spaces back in.

However, I get the console error

`*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]`

Followed by this (although I don't think its important):

```
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff84a08b06 __exceptionPreprocess + 198
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8c72f3f0 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff849a58ec -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 252
    3   G-Clock                             0x0000000100001ff1 -[GCAppController tick:] + 1937
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff8a011d05 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 358
    5   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff849c5804 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 20
    6   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff849c531d __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 557
    7   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff849aaad9 __CFRunLoopRun + 1529
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff849aa0e2 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 290
    9   HIToolbox                           0x00007fff83bbdeb4 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 209
    10  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff83bbdb94 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 166
    11  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff83bbdae3 BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInMode + 62
    12  AppKit                              0x00007fff88b7a533 _DPSNextEvent + 685
    13  AppKit                              0x00007fff88b79df2 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 128
    14  AppKit                              0x00007fff88b711a3 -[NSApplication run] + 517
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff88b15bd6 NSApplicationMain + 869
    16  G-Clock                             0x0000000100000ea2 main + 34
    17  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff864fc7e1 start + 0
    18  ???                                 0x0000000000000003 0x0 + 3
)
```

I can't figure out whats wrong, let alone how to change it.

My code, with str being input and str2 being output:

```
//Convert to binary
        NSMutableString *str2 = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@""];
        int count = -1;
        NSArray *array = [str componentsSeparatedByString: @" "];
        NSUInteger numObjects = [array count];
        //Converts each object of array into binary separately, so spaces remain intact.
        while (1) {
            ++count;
            NSString *string = array[count];
            NSMutableString *mutStr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@""];
            for (NSInteger numberCopy = [string intValue]; numberCopy > 0; numberCopy >>=1) {
                //Prepend "0" or "1", depending on the bit
                [mutStr insertString:((numberCopy & 1) ? @"1" : @"0") atIndex:0];
            }
            if (numObjects != count + 1) {
                //Add space if this is not last run through
                [mutStr appendString: @" "];
            } else break;
            [str2 appendString: mutStr];
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have *two* places in the loop where `count` is incremented.
Also `mutStr` must be appended to `str2` in any case.

But I would use a for-loop instead:

```
for (count = 0; count < numObjects; count++) {
    NSString *string = array[count];
    NSMutableString *mutStr = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@""];
    for (NSInteger numberCopy = [string intValue]; numberCopy > 0; numberCopy >>=1) {
        //Prepend "0" or "1", depending on the bit
        [mutStr insertString:((numberCopy & 1) ? @"1" : @"0") atIndex:0];
    }
    [str2 appendString: mutStr];
    if (numObjects != count + 1) {
        //Add space if this is not last run through
        [str2 appendString: @" "];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats something that definitely wouldn't have let my code work, but unfortunately it wasn't the solution. Editing that in.

Comment: @jazz14456: There was another error in your code, see updated answer.

Comment: I posted it too at the same time :). I'll accept yours because your not the asker and you did the first part about `count + 1` instead of `++count` along with the last error

Comment: Also add my answer to your answer before I accept, because it won't work without that part.

Comment: @jazz14456: I have now added another variant which does also work, and is easier to read in my opinion.

Comment: Man, I was just going to accept it, but this does look much better aesthetically, and it's easier to read. It looks like it should run slightly faster too, which is important to me because I'm using it in a clock app. :D +1

Answer (score 0):

It was a logic error. After @Martin 's part, on the last run, the `else break` was after the part where `[array count]` was called, and since there was no array object at that index of count, the program broke.

```
while (1) {
    ++count;
    if (count == numbObjects) 
       break;
    ...
    }
```